# how to import and export an excel file using asp.net web api 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I want to do the following I want to be able to upload a file using asp.net web API from a local disk storage to memory and then compress the memory stream and save the memory stream to a db. Also I would like to export the compressed stream back as file name.zip when requested.

I do not know where to start can someone help.

I have tried all searches and tutorials none helped in showing me how to upload to memory stream

ok the following is the the steps I want to do that I need help it I will be grateful if any one can show me

1. I want to Create an asp.net web api that dose the following

   a. Users of the api Will be able to upload and excel file into memory

   b. The memory stream that the file has been uploaded into gets zipped in memory.

   c. The memory stream is stored into an mssql database.
2. The user of the api sends a request to the api

   a. the file is read back into a memory stream from the db as a zip file

   b. the file is then downloaded to the user as a zip file

The above is the break down if any would like to help me i will gladly appreciate it.

Also I would Gladly appreciate it if someone can point me to the right direction links and 
videos.

Comment: Do you want to extract contents of an excel sheet to a db ?

Comment: It is very surprising that no one tried to load file from disk to memory or compress files into Zip archive using C#... Please consider breaking your task in separate steps and ask concrete question about each one (assuming you can't find any information or all information is not helpful).

Comment: Alex levenkov ok will edit and split

Comment: @KCdod To answer your question no the compressed memory stream will be saved as is into the db ...

Answer (score 1):

Well after doing small research on the web i found phace one of what i want to do here is the code i hope it helps some one.:

A Basic Controller Accepting Uploads to MemoryStream

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
  public async Task Post()
  {
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
          throw new    HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable,"This request is not properly formatted"));

    var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
    await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

    foreach (HttpContent ctnt in provider.Contents)
    {
        //now read individual part into STREAM
        var stream = await ctnt.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        if (stream.Length != 0)
        {
            //handle the stream here
        }
    }
}
```

I will add snippets of code when i find the rest of the answer to my question.